# jax ws client ip as username

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jaas

In an "old" Project i use a EJB Jax WS Webservice.The old version is secured by a Interceptor wich read the API Token as Securitymechanism. The API Tokens are allready mapped to the IP.  Now i want to use Securitymechanism to use the request IP as Username and an API Token as Password. I Thought the easiest way to implement this is to use the @AllowedRoles annotation and the container Realm. my problem is now how can i set the client ip as username on server side to prevent fake submits.

First Idea was to use SoapHandler but they are note invoked before authentication!

Comment: Maybe this link can help http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java/

Comment: how i can get the client ip is not the problem, my problem is how can i set the username(the client ip) before authentication.